# Custimizing Matplotlib plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, latex

I am trying to implement a custimizing procedure of matplotlib plots for the use of a latex work. For more reference please take a look at the following link: [LaTeXify Matplotlib](https://nipunbatra.github.io/blog/2014/latexify.html)

The following piece of code shows what I have tried. I implemented the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib

from math import sqrt
SPINE_COLOR = 'gray'

def latexify(fig_width=None, fig_height=None, columns=1):
    """Set up matplotlib's RC params for LaTeX plotting.
    Call this before plotting a figure.

    Parameters
    ----------
    fig_width : float, optional, inches
    fig_height : float,  optional, inches
    columns : {1, 2}
    """

    # code adapted from http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/LaTeX_Examples

    # Width and max height in inches for IEEE journals taken from
    # computer.org/cms/Computer.org/Journal%20templates/transactions_art_guide.pdf

    assert(columns in [1,2])

    if fig_width is None:
        fig_width = 3.39 if columns==1 else 6.9 # width in inches

    if fig_height is None:
        golden_mean = (sqrt(5)-1.0)/2.0    # Aesthetic ratio
        fig_height = fig_width*golden_mean # height in inches

    MAX_HEIGHT_INCHES = 8.0
    if fig_height > MAX_HEIGHT_INCHES:
        print("WARNING: fig_height too large:" + fig_height +
              "so will reduce to" + MAX_HEIGHT_INCHES + "inches.")
        fig_height = MAX_HEIGHT_INCHES

    params = {'backend': 'ps',
              'text.latex.preamble':['\usepackage{gensymb}'],
              'axes.labelsize': 8, # fontsize for x and y labels (was 10)
              'axes.titlesize': 8,
              'text.fontsize': 8, # was 10
              'legend.fontsize': 8, # was 10
              'xtick.labelsize': 8,
              'ytick.labelsize': 8,
              'text.usetex': True,
              'figure.figsize': [fig_width,fig_height],
              'font.family': 'serif'
    }

    matplotlib.rcParams.update(params)


def latexify(fig_width=None, fig_height=None, columns=1):
    """Set up matplotlib's RC params for LaTeX plotting.
    Call this before plotting a figure.

    Parameters
    ----------
    fig_width : float, optional, inches
    fig_height : float,  optional, inches
    columns : {1, 2}
    """

    # code adapted from http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/LaTeX_Examples

    # Width and max height in inches for IEEE journals taken from
    # computer.org/cms/Computer.org/Journal%20templates/transactions_art_guide.pdf

    assert(columns in [1,2])

    if fig_width is None:
        fig_width = 3.39 if columns==1 else 6.9 # width in inches

    if fig_height is None:
        golden_mean = (sqrt(5)-1.0)/2.0    # Aesthetic ratio
        fig_height = fig_width*golden_mean # height in inches

    MAX_HEIGHT_INCHES = 8.0
    if fig_height > MAX_HEIGHT_INCHES:
        print("WARNING: fig_height too large:" + fig_height +
              "so will reduce to" + MAX_HEIGHT_INCHES + "inches.")
        fig_height = MAX_HEIGHT_INCHES

    params = {'backend': 'ps',
              'text.latex.preamble': ['\usepackage{gensymb}'],
              'axes.labelsize': 8, # fontsize for x and y labels (was 10)
              'axes.titlesize': 8,
              'text.fontsize': 8, # was 10
              'legend.fontsize': 8, # was 10
              'xtick.labelsize': 8,
              'ytick.labelsize': 8,
              'text.usetex': True,
              'figure.figsize': [fig_width,fig_height],
              'font.family': 'serif'
    }

    matplotlib.rcParams.update(params)


def format_axes(ax):

    for spine in ['top', 'right']:
        ax.spines[spine].set_visible(False)

    for spine in ['left', 'bottom']:
        ax.spines[spine].set_color(SPINE_COLOR)
        ax.spines[spine].set_linewidth(0.5)

    ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
    ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')

    for axis in [ax.xaxis, ax.yaxis]:
        axis.set_tick_params(direction='out', color=SPINE_COLOR)

    return ax

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,2))
df.columns = ['Column 1', 'Column 2']



ax = df.plot()
ax.set_xlabel("X label")
ax.set_ylabel("Y label")
ax.set_title("Title")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig("C:\Users\Laptop\Desktop\image1.pdf")


latexify()

ax = df.plot()
ax.set_xlabel("X label")
ax.set_ylabel("Y label")
ax.set_title("Title")
plt.tight_layout()
format_axes(ax)
plt.savefig("C:\Users\Laptop\Desktop\image2.pdf")
```

I obtain the following Syntaxerror and complete traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.3.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.3.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/Laptop/PycharmProjects/PythonThesisVU/PLOTS.py", line 41
    'text.latex.preamble':['\usepackage{gensymb}'],
                          ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: truncated \uXXXX escape
```

Does anybody know why it gives the syntax error and how I could make the code run smoothly without any errors?

Any help would be much appreciated!

EDIT 1: Adjust the font family to avant.

```
params = {'backend': 'ps',
          'text.latex.preamble':[r'\usepackage{gensymb}', r'\usepackage{avant}'],
          'axes.labelsize': 8, # fontsize for x and y labels (was 10)
          'axes.titlesize': 8,
          'font.size': 8, # was 10
          'legend.fontsize': 8, # was 10
          'xtick.labelsize': 8,
          'ytick.labelsize': 8,
          'text.usetex': True,
          'figure.figsize': [fig_width,fig_height],
          'font.family': 'avant'
```

The desired avant font looks like this: [image]

Comment: Please post the full traceback, which will tell readers exactly where the error occurs in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the insightful comment. I just added the complete traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is occurring at this line:

```
          'text.latex.preamble':['\usepackage{gensymb}'],
```

Python interprets the `\u` in `'\usepackage{gensymb}'` as the start of a [Unicode escape sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#unicode-literals-in-python-source-code). You can fix this by either escaping the `\` with `\\` or by using a raw string.

For example:

```
          'text.latex.preamble':[r'\usepackage{gensymb}'],
```

or:

```
          'text.latex.preamble':['\\usepackage{gensymb}'],
```

will correct the error.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. This was indeed the error. I marked your comment as the answer.

Comment: Craig, Would you know how to adjust the font.family to avant so it would match neatly the textformat. This would require loading the \usepackage{avant}. so I tried the following (please see EDIT 1).

Comment: I'm not familiar with the latex fonts. Please ask a new question about setting the font to avant.

Answer (score 0):

`text.fontsize` is not a valid parameter. It's `font.size` instead. Also backslashes must be escaped or a raw string must be used. `r'\usepackage{gensymb}'`

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply as well and you're right.  Fortunately, Python was very explicit telling me that text.fontsize was incorrect. Thanks!

Comment: If you'd know a way how to make the font family compatible with avant as given in EDIT 1, that would be highly appreciated.